Using group representation to prove the rigidity of CHSH, puzzled in one step
I am reading this lecture note: UCSD Summer school notes
Quantum multiplayer games, testing and rigidity. In the proof of the following theorem:

the group $H=\pm\{I,X,Z,XZ\}$ is considered. Let $$f(\pm I)=\pm I, f(\pm X)= \pm A_0,f(\pm Z) = \pm A_1, f(\pm XZ)=\pm A_0A_1.$$ Here $A_0,A_1$ are observables. Then it is claimed that $f$ is a $(O(\varepsilon), \rho_A)$-approximate representation of $H$, which is defined as follows:

Here, $\langle X,Z\rangle_Y:={\rm tr}(XZ^\dagger Y)$ and $\|X\|_Y:=(\langle X,X\rangle_Y)^{1/2})$.
My question is that it seem that $f$ is a homomorphism, that is $f(xy^{-1})=f(x)f(y)^{*}$, for example, $x=X,y=Z$, $f(xy^{-1})=f(XZ)=A_0A_1=f(x)f(y)^{*}$, and also for other cases. Then $f$ is a group representation not only an approximate representation. But obviously there must be somewhere wrong because the proof is using equation 10 (that is $A_0,A_1$ are nearly anti-commute in the sense $\|A_0A_1 + A_1A_0\|^2_{\rho_A}= O(\varepsilon)$) as a prerequisite to conclude that $f$ is an approximate representation. So what is wrong here?

Theorem 12 only states that $f$ is a function. Not that it is a representation. I think this is where your misunderstanding stems from but I may be wrong as I'm not an expert on this.

@Rammus I miswrote it, it is Theorem 14. I think Theorem 12 is saying that for an approximate representation on a group, there exist an exact group representation close to the approximate one. But the $f$ given in the proof seems like an exact group representation.

(Edited the post such that, hopefully, all relevant information is now part of the question itself)

The map is defined as you state, which means that the relation $f(XZ) = f(X)f(Z) = A_0 A_1$ is satisfied by construction. However, it is not necessarily the case that $f(ZX)$ equals $f(Z)f(X) = A_1 A_0$ exactly. In these notes the action of $f$ on $ZX$ is defined by $$f(ZX) = f(-XZ) = -f(X)f(Z) = -A_0 A_1.$$ We only get the homomorphism property if $A_0$ and $A_1$ anticommute, and get an approximate homomorphism if they approximately anticommute.
